# Base64 encoded data is not uploading as PNG image in AWS s3 bucket in GO

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am trying to upload base64 encoded string to aws s3 bucket in the form of PNG image. I had tried following code:

```
import (
    awsconfig "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/config"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/feature/s3/manager"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/s3"
)
signature:= "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"
decodedSignature, decodeErr := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(signature)
if decodeErr != nil {
    // handle error here
}
r := bytes.NewReader(decodedSignature)

bucketName := "test"
filepath := "uploads"
contentType := "image/png"
cfg, err := awsconfig.LoadDefaultConfig(context.TODO(),
    awsconfig.WithRegion(config.AwsRegion),
)
client := s3.NewFromConfig(cfg)

// Create an uploader with the client and options
uploader := manager.NewUploader(client)
cacheExpireTime := time.Now().AddDate(1, 0, 0)
cacheMaxAgeSecs := "31556926" // seconds in 1 year

// Upload the file to S3.
uploadResp, err := uploader.Upload(context.TODO(), &s3.PutObjectInput{
    Bucket:       aws.String(bucketName),
    Key:          aws.String(filePath),
    Body:         r,
    ContentType:  aws.String(contentType),
    Expires:      &cacheExpireTime,
    CacheControl: aws.String(cacheMaxAgeSecs),
})
```

But when I try to load the s3 url on which the image is uploaded, then there is black screen as shown in the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Could you share the `go.mod` file, please?

Comment: I did not include go.mod file

Comment: alright, could you tell me which packages you are using and their corresponding versions?

Comment: The SDK used is updated in the post

Comment: the only odd thing I see is that your `CacheControl` setting is invalid; it should look like `max-age=<number-of-seconds>` instead of just a number of seconds. https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9 Try leaving that option out and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: NO, that did not make any difference

Answer (score 1):

The `Body` parameter in the `uploader.Upload` function accepts `io.Reader` objects as body, meaning that you either need to use `os.Open` to open a png you have saved, or in this case, use `bytes.NewReader(data)` to make your data conform to the `io.Reader` interface (have the `.Read()` method).

Comment: I didn't get what you are trying to say because I have already used `bytes.NewReader()` in the code.

Comment: Right, have you tried `data:image/png;base64,` before the signature? Where are the images going to be coming from in the app?

Comment: I did not understand your question.

Comment: Are you going to be getting the images from user uploads? In case you would like to display the image in html you need to include the `data:image/png;base64,` before the base64 encoded image string. However, if the users are to upload files, you could just upload the raw object and not worry about encoding the image into base64.

Comment: First of all, users are to upload files so I have no option to directly display the image in html. Secondly, how can I upload the raw object ? should I upload the signature string in txt file ?